# about Controlling GPIO in CP210x C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am trying to control the CP2108-EK by referring to the link below.

[Controlling GPIO in CP210x C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914716/controlling-gpio-in-cp210x-c-sharp)

And when I open a message box and check the return values ​​of the methods, the following values ​​came out.

```
retVal = CP210x.Open(3, ref handle);
 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("" + retVal);//3 fail
```

---

```
 retVal = CP210x.WriteLatch(handle, (UInt16)(mask << idx), 0x01);
 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("" + retVal);//255 device not found
```

For the result of the return values, refer to CP210xManufacturingDLL.h and CP210xManufacturingDLL.h.

Is it impossible to control CP2108-EK with C# Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

This problem I solved.

This was solved by using the latest dll file that was included with the driver folder.